# I'm trying to remake Vuex's Getting Started project using several components but can't figure out how to invoke root methods from components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

The project in question is [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/n9jmu5v7/1269/), simple and straightforward, but for the sake of learning I broke it down into index and 4 js files (parent, child, root and store) and I can't figure out how to invoke increment and decrement root methods in the child without using the commits inside the elements, or falling into bad practices or anti-patterns, such as using props or `this.$root` inside the elements.

Here's my code:

**index.html:**

```
<div id="app">
        <parent></parent>
</div>
```

**root.js:**

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    methods:{
        increment(){
            store.commit('incrementar')
        },
        decrement(){
            store.commit('decrementar')
        } 
    }
})
```

**store.js:**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        numero: 11
    },
    mutations:{
        incrementar(state){
            state.numero++
        },
        decrementar(state){
            state.numero--
        }
    }
})
```

**parent.js:**

```
Vue.component('parent',{
    template:
    `
    <div>
        <h1>Numero: {{$store.state.numero}}</h1>
        <child></child>
    </div>
    `
})
```

**child.js:**

```
Vue.component('child',{
    template:
    `
    <div>
        <button @click="increment">+</button>
        <button @click="decrement">-</button>
        <h1>Numero: {{numero}}</h1>
    </div>
    `,
    computed: {
        numero() {
            return store.state.numero
        }
      }
```

I read that I should use events but I'm not sure exactly how with the buttons. It comes without saying that I'm pretty new to JavaScript, Vue and Vuex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use instance methods events as it [described here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events), for example:

**root.js:**

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
  mounted () {
    let self = this
    self.$root.$on('FancyEventName', self.HandleFancyEvent)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    let self = this
    self.$root.$off('FancyEventName', self.HandleFancyEvent)
  },
  methods: {
    HandleFancyEvent (arg) {
      let self = this
      if(arg === true){
       self.increment()
     } else{
       self.decrement()
     }
    },
    methods:{
        increment(){
            store.commit('incrementar')
        },
        decrement(){
            store.commit('decrementar')
        } 
    }
})
```

**child.js:**

```
Vue.component('child',{
    template:
    `
    <div>
        <button @click="increment">+</button>
        <button @click="decrement">-</button>
        <h1>Numero: {{numero}}</h1>
    </div>
    `,
    methods:{
        increment(){
            let self = this
            self.$root.$emit('FancyEventName', true)
        },
        decrement(){
            let self = this
            self.$root.$emit('FancyEventName', false)
        } 
    }
    computed: {
        numero() {
            return store.state.numero
        }
      }
```

It will work just fine. Also, I've seen some people taking approach of using separate instance to do the same thing.

You can create an "EventBus" and use it like this:

```
// event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

And here is a component which emits an event:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import EventBus from './event-bus';
Vue.component('component-a', {
  ...
  methods: {
    emitMethod () {
       EventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME', payLoad);
    }
  }
});
```

And a second component which reacts to this event:

```
// component-b.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import EventBus from './event-bus';
Vue.component(‘component-b’, {
  ...
  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on(‘EVENT_NAME’, function (payLoad) {
      ...
    });
  }
});
```

As you may see it does it the same way, the only difference is - you are using separate instance for communication purposes.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its a lot more code than expected though. The first solution is pretty straighforward, the second one is a bit confusing, ive seen solutions like that but i fail to realize how to implement it in my case.

Comment: @JoaquinLeon I hope it helps. The only advantage of second approach (as far as I can see) it will work even if you are using different `Vue` instances per page. Well, let me know if I can help.

Comment: I got rid of the root methods and took the mapMutations route instead. It looks much cleaner and simple, though im sure ill have to resort to some of your suggestions in the future.